# Snowflake appending string at the beginning

Tags: string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column which holds values as below from which I wanted to check if the first character is R after removing the leading zeros, If the first character is not equal to R then add at the beginning as shown in the expected values.

```
Column value
------------
00002349954
123456
R34854-1
R1234-3
01278993
345677
```

I want the above values to be formed as below. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

```
Expected Values
---------------
R2349954
R123456
R34854-1
R1234-3
R1278993
R345677
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select 'R' || ltrim(v,'0R' ) 
from values ('00002349954'),('R1234-3'),('123456') tmp(v);

+-----------------------+
| 'R' || LTRIM(V,'0R' ) |
+-----------------------+
| R2349954              |
| R1234-3               |
| R123456               |
+-----------------------+
```

LTRIM https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ltrim.html

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I wasn't aware that LTRIM is that powerful in Snowflake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no whitespaces in your values you may use this:

1. Remove leading zeros: `REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(colname, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')`
2. Add a leading "R": `CONCAT('R', colname)`

In your case to meet your requirements something like the following should work:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
 WHEN REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(colname, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') like 'R%' THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(colname, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
 ELSE CONCAT('R',REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(colname, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'))
```